# Volume of revolution around a line

Tags: calculus, volume

Find the volume of revoulution of the region enclosed by $y = x^3, x = 0, x = 1$ and $y=-1$ around the axis $y = -1$.

This question is most easily done via the disk method, however, I tried cylindrical shells and I have an incorrect answer.

The region is composed of two sections: A square with side 1 in the fourth quadrant and a region enclosed by $y=x^3$ in the first quadrant.  So using shells, I believe I need to split the integral up, since the shells will be varying in height:

For ths lower region, I have $2\pi \int_{-1}^0 y\,dy = \pi$  For the upper region, I have $2 \pi\int_{0}^1 (1+y)(1-y^{1/3})\,dy = \frac{9\pi}{14}$  Evaluating and adding together yields an incorrect answer.

Many thanks.

Comment: Is the correct answer $\,\displaystyle{\frac{8\pi}7}\;$ ?

Comment: No, it is $\frac{16\pi}{7}$.  I got $\frac{8 \pi}{7}$, like you did, but it is out by a factor of 2.  My integrals make sense, so I can't see my error. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you made a small typo; the lower region should be set up as:
$$2\pi \int_{-1}^0 -y\,dy = \pi$$

Thus, your total volume would be: $\pi+\dfrac{9\pi}{14}=\dfrac{14\pi}{14}+\dfrac{9\pi}{14}=\boxed{\dfrac{23\pi}{14}}$

Otherwise, your method looks correct. The easier solution via the disk method yields the same answer:
$$\pi \int_0^1 (x^3+1)^2dx = \boxed{\dfrac{23\pi}{14}}$$

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it says the answer is 16pi/7?

Comment: What you did makes more sense: To get 16pi/7, they did $$\int_{-1}^{1} (1 + x^3)^2 dx$$, however, x varies from 0 to 1 clearly as you said, not from -1 to 1. I accept your answer.

Comment: I can understand now why my answer, and yours @CAF, is half what they gave, yet I've no idea how in the world the did decide to integrat over $\,[-1,1]\,$ instead of over $\,[0,1],$ , as given in the problem...